# Store foreign key as eccrypted and fetch be decrypt

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I am implementing a user management system using django ORM. It is said to store the Password in a different table named "user_password" and encrypt the the foreign key "id" of "user_password" table in "User" table to preserved the relation between them. I implemented it by defining no database level relationship between the two tables. I mean the tables are fully seperated with no real foreign key relatiob. Is their any way to store and fetch the foreign relation object by encryting and decrypting the foreign key field while preserving the foreign key relation in database?